# XSL Transform remove Xml Elements

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I am stumped. Given an xml doc like:

```
    <Frag>
        <DirRef Id="BeemzDir">
            <Com Id="BEED24F05AB78FB588F61D4092654B6D" Guid="{A11AB356-2F45-4157-92EF-ED49F5BE0F70}">
                <FileName Id="fil1" KeyPath="yes" Source="My.Exe" />
            </Com>
            <Com Id="FFF24F05AB78FB588F61D4092654CCC" Guid="{A11AB356-2F45-4157-92EF-ED49F5BE0F70}">
                <FileName Id="fil2" KeyPath="yes" Source="My.Dll" />
            </Com> 
          </DirRef>
</Frag>
<Frag>
        <ComGroup Id="MyGroup">
            <CompRef Id="BEED24F05AB78FB588F61D4092654B6D" />
            <CompRef Id="FFF24F05AB78FB588F61D4092654CCC" />
        </ComGroup>  
</Frag>
```

I need to use xslt to remove the element that houses the Source="My.Exe". In this case remove element "Com" where its attribute id=BEED24F05AB78FB588F61D4092654B6D.

I have done that. But what I cant do is also remove the "CompRef" element where Id=BEED24F05AB78FB588F61D4092654B6D.

So after transformation I want my xml to look like:

```
    <Frag>
        <DirRef Id="BeemzDir">
            <Com Id="FFF24F05AB78FB588F61D4092654CCC" Guid="{A11AB356-2F45-4157-92EF-ED49F5BE0F70}">
                <FileName Id="fil2" KeyPath="yes" Source="My.Dll" />
            </Com> 
          </DirRef>
</Frag>
<Frag>
        <ComGroup Id="MyGroup">
            <CompRef Id="FFF24F05AB78FB588F61D4092654CCC" />
        </ComGroup>  
</Frag>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

***Update***

Here is some xml that deletes the "FileName" element.

```
  <xsl:template match="Com/FileName[contains(@Source,'My.Exe')='true']">
  </xsl:template>
```

So that results in:

```
<Frag>
    <DirRef Id="BeemzDir">
        <Com Id="BEED24F05AB78FB588F61D4092654B6D" Guid="{A11AB356-2F45-4157-92EF-ED49F5BE0F70}">

        </Com>
        <Com Id="FFF24F05AB78FB588F61D4092654CCC" Guid="{A11AB356-2F45-4157-92EF-ED49F5BE0F70}">
            <FileName Id="fil2" KeyPath="yes" Source="My.Dll" />
        </Com> 
          </DirRef>
</Frag>
<Frag>
        <ComGroup Id="MyGroup">
            <CompRef Id="BEED24F05AB78FB588F61D4092654B6D" />
            <CompRef Id="FFF24F05AB78FB588F61D4092654CCC" />
        </ComGroup>  
</Frag>
```

Changing the above xsl that calls an xsl:apply-template doesn nothing, as its stuck in the node its operating in. I dont know how to store the Ids I want to delete and then loop through them.

**Update 2**

There can be more than one node to delete, that is multiple "Com" elements where source="MyExe". Also the Id is autogenerated so will be different each this is run.

Comment: Show us what you've already tried.  Also, did you use an "Identity Transform" along with special case templates for the tags you want to remove?   If you don't know what an "XSL Identity Transform" is, use Google.

Comment: Jim, trust me, I have been googling and plodding through this for hours. I just don't get xml and xslt :-)

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Com[FileName/@Source='My.Exe']"/>

 <xsl:template match="CompRef[@Id=/*/*/*/Com[FileName/@Source='My.Exe']/@Id]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document (corrected to be made well-formed):**

```
<Frags>
    <Frag>
        <DirRef Id="BeemzDir">
            <Com Id="BEED24F05AB78FB588F61D4092654B6D" Guid="{A11AB356-2F45-4157-92EF-ED49F5BE0F70}">
                <FileName Id="fil1" KeyPath="yes" Source="My.Exe" />
            </Com>
            <Com Id="FFF24F05AB78FB588F61D4092654CCC" Guid="{A11AB356-2F45-4157-92EF-ED49F5BE0F70}">
                <FileName Id="fil2" KeyPath="yes" Source="My.Dll" />
            </Com>
        </DirRef>
    </Frag>
    <Frag>
        <ComGroup Id="MyGroup">
            <CompRef Id="BEED24F05AB78FB588F61D4092654B6D" />
            <CompRef Id="FFF24F05AB78FB588F61D4092654CCC" />
        </ComGroup>
    </Frag>
</Frags>
```

**produces the wanted, correct output**:

```
<Frags>
    <Frag>
        <DirRef Id="BeemzDir">
            <Com Id="FFF24F05AB78FB588F61D4092654CCC" Guid="{A11AB356-2F45-4157-92EF-ED49F5BE0F70}">
                <FileName Id="fil2" KeyPath="yes" Source="My.Dll"/>
            </Com>
        </DirRef>
    </Frag>
    <Frag>
        <ComGroup Id="MyGroup">
            <CompRef Id="FFF24F05AB78FB588F61D4092654CCC"/>
        </ComGroup>
    </Frag>
</Frags>
```

Comment: Good one! Also, You could add one stylesheet with `xsl:key`, as there is cross references.

Comment: @Alejandro: Sure, I hope I'll find time this evening.

Comment: Amazing... this question just ended 3 hours of googeling XSL and made my WiX installer work. Thanks!.

Answer (score -1):

This is REALLY quick and untested but you want the selector attribute to not be equal to a value:

```
<xsl:template match="node()[!@Id='BEED24F05AB78FB588F61D4092654B6D']">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="frag"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()|processing-instruction()|comment()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates
      select="@*|node()|processing-instruction()|comment()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Mark, I will try in the morning. Its 2:15am and I am calling it quits for tonight. I updated the question with some more detail...in any case thanks for giving up some of your time..

Comment: `node()|processing-instruction()|comment()` is redundant.  `node()` matches all node types - text nodes, elements, processing instructions, and comments.  The only thing it doesn't match are attributes, which aren't nodes, which is why the pattern to match everything is `@*|node()`.

Comment: negation in XPath is `not()` function. In this case you could use "not equal" operator `!=`. Also, with your stylesheet you are saying: "copy everything (even nodes without this @Id) but `frag` elements". So, the result is nothing in this case.

Comment: @Robert Rossney - thanks for pointing that out.  @Alejando, thanks for that, I knew I was posting this too fast :(